# Redirect Domain1 to HTTP non-www to HTTPS www - Domain2 without HTTPS htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've a multistore with Opencart. Domain1 uses HTTPS and domain2 uses HTTP. I've the following settings in my .htaccess because I want both domains redirecting to HTTP(S)://www.

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 



RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
#RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
## domain1 ##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.nl/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain1.nl/$1 [L,R=301] 

## domain2 ##



### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Domain1 is working fine but when I visit domain2 it shows me domain1.

Does anyone know the correct .htaccess settings?

Comment: Under what condition you want URL to be redirected to `domain2`?

Comment: Hi I want the non-www redirecting to http:// www. domain2.nl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

## domain1 ##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain1.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] 

## domain2 ##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain2.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Thank you for your reply but it didn't work. I'm getting an error when I try to visit domain1.

Comment: The error was a redirect loop. I'm tryinig to access https:// www. dartshopper.nl and http:// www. dartsinkopen.nl

Comment: I've changed my question. Yes I'm using Opencart if that's what you mean with CMS Framework.

Comment: I've tried your code but it doesn't work. When I use my current code I see under resources www.dartshopper.nl but with your code I don't see anything: (data:text/html,chro...). How can I see the redirects?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. First it redirects to dartshopper.nl, then to dartsinkopen.nl, then back to dartshopper.nl. I can't find anything in dev tool only this: Request URL:data:text/html,chromewebdata

Comment: dartshopper.nl works, dartsinkopen.nl redirects to www. dartsinkopen.nl but www. dartsinkopen.nl redirects to https:// www. dartshopper.nl

Comment: Cross domain redirection cannot happen due to first `RewriteCond` in both rules. Are you sure you've changed domain1 and domain2 correctly?

Comment: THANKS! It worked. The redirect was happening because of my cookies.